# Entity relationship multiple inheritance issue

Tags: c#, database, entity-relationship, multi-table-inheritance

I have this entity model:

[image: Entity Object Model]

I want to have a `Customer` entity, which can be either a `Person` or an `Organization`, It can't be both.

As of now I came up with a customer entity which points to both organization and person but with a nullable field (meaning `Guid?`), which means having a non-mandatory relationship with `Person` and `Organization`. Something like:

```
class Customer
{
    public Guid ID { get; set; }
    public Guid? RelatedPersonID { get; set; }
    public Guid? RelatedOrganizationID { get; set; }
    public int CustomerStatus { get; set; }
    public bool IsVIP { get; set; }
    // ... other customer related properties

    public virtual Person RelatedPerson { get; set; }
    public virtual Organization RelatedOrganization { get; set; }
}
```

I'm using entity framework 5, codefirst approach and I haven't created the database yet. I was wondering if there's a better model that meets this requirements.

Comment: do you have Organizations in your system which are not customers? may be you can also consider to make all customers as organisations with person as a contact within the organisation. this would simplify things.

Comment: @ravi: unfortunately yes, an organization might not be a customer, it may be a supplier, I have the same problem for Supplier as for Customer!

Comment: I don't like nullable foreign keys because you have to explain how it works to somebody for them to understand and its not self explanatory.  I would personally try abstracting out the common fields between the person customer and organisation customer as an interface and implement it in both person customer and organisation customer.

Comment: @ravi So you duplicate the common fields in 2 tables ? and in code use an interface to abstract it. One of the pros of this is that we have a consistent Conceptual Design. but one the cons is when you want to change a common field or add a new common field, you should do it in 2 places. I think if you make your comment as an answer would be nice. So we can discuss it more. Thnx